# Como passar mais de um parâmetro para um Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Estou precisando de um apoio para passar mais de um parâmetro para um Controller de Criação. 
Tenho algumas models conforme abaixo:

- `Usuario` : Traz as informações do usuário que abriu o chamado ex. id_usuario, nome_usuario
- `Chamado` : Traz o título, conteúdo, id_do usuário, data, etc
- `Evolucao` : Contém o id_evolucao, id_chamado, id_usuario, Texto_evolucao

Quando vou criar uma nova evolução preciso passar para o Controller o **id_chamado** (definindo o chamado ao qual ela faz parte) e também o **id_usuario** (criador da evolução do chamado), além das demais informações.

Qual a maneira mais prática de implementar esse recurso?

Comment: O que é controller de criação? Procurei na internet mas não encontrei nada a respeito. Onde você está com problemas? Na chamada da URL? "vou criar uma nova evolução": O que é evolução?

Answer (score 2):

A maneira correta é usando *ViewModel*:

```
namespace SeuProjeto.ViewModels
{
    public class CriarEvolucaoViewModel
    {
        public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
        public Chamado Chamado { get; set; }
        public Evolucao Evolucao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Na *Action* `GET`, você terá que trazer todos os possíveis registros e inicializar o objeto *ViewModel*:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
    {
        ViewBag.UsuariosPossiveis = db.Usuarios.ToList();
        ViewBag.ChamadosPossiveis = db.Chamados.ToList();
        return View(new CriarEvolucaoViewModel 
        {
            Usuario = new Usuario(),
            Chamado = new Chamado(),
            Evolucao = new Evolucao()
        });
    }
```

*View*:

```
@model SeuProjeto.ViewModels.CriarEvolucaoViewModel
@using SeuProjeto.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Evolucao</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Usuario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Usuario.UsuarioId, 
                    ((IEnumerable<Usuario>)ViewBag.UsuariosPossiveis).Select(option => new SelectListItem 
                {
                    Text = option.Nome,
                    Value = option.UsuarioId.ToString()
                }),
                new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Usuario.UsuarioId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Chamado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Chamado.ChamadoId, 
                    ((IEnumerable<Usuario>)ViewBag.ChamadosPossiveis).Select(option => new SelectListItem 
                {
                    Text = option.Titulo,
                    Value = option.ChamadoId.ToString()
                }),
                new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Chamado.ChamadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Texto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Texto, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Texto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

A *Action* do *Controller* que receberá isso é algo assim:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CriarEvolucaoViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Aqui você pode fazer verificações adicionais, se quiser.

            var novaEvolucao = new Evolucao
            {
                EvolucaoId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Usuario = db.Usuarios.Single(u => u.UsuarioId == viewModel.Usuario.UsuarioId),
                Chamado = db.Chamados.Single(c => c.ChamadoId == viewModel.Chamado.ChamadoId),
            }

            db.Evolucoes.Add(novaEvolucao);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

A vantagem deste método é que você pode criar também `Usuario` e `Chamado` na mesma tela, só colocando os campos apropriadamente e modificando a lógica de inserção.

Se você não vai inserir `Usuario` e `Chamado`, dá pra fazer mais simples:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
    {
        ViewBag.UsuariosPossiveis = db.Usuarios.ToList();
        ViewBag.ChamadosPossiveis = db.Chamados.ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

*View*:

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.Evolucao
@using SeuProjeto.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Evolucao</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Usuario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UsuarioId, 
                    ((IEnumerable<Usuario>)ViewBag.UsuariosPossiveis).Select(option => new SelectListItem 
                {
                    Text = option.Nome,
                    Value = option.UsuarioId.ToString()
                }),
                new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UsuarioId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Chamado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChamadoId, 
                    ((IEnumerable<Usuario>)ViewBag.ChamadosPossiveis).Select(option => new SelectListItem 
                {
                    Text = option.Titulo,
                    Value = option.ChamadoId.ToString()
                }),
                new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChamadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Texto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Texto, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Texto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Action `POST`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ChamadoId,UsuarioId,Texto")]Evolucao evolucao)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Aqui você pode fazer verificações adicionais, se quiser.

            db.Evolucoes.Add(evolucao);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(evolucao);
    }
```

Comment: Olá Cigano, fiz a implementação de acordo com sua sugestão e ficou legal. Porém os atributos de id_usuario e id_chamado ficaram com o valor 0 no bind do Create (ao debugar pude constatar essa informação). Teoricamente não era para ele receber esses valores da view? O que posso estar esquecendo de fazer?

Comment: Qual das abordagens você usou?

Comment: Eu utilizei a segunda abordagem, porém ela também me traz a possibilidade de escolher não só o chamado como o usuário que vai fazer a evolução (através das dropdowns). O que eu busco é precisamente fazer evoluções num chamado (selecionado numa lista anterior) e ao ver o histórico de evoluções deste, poder fazer novas interações para o chamado em específico. Com isso, deverá ficar vinculado à evolução o usuário que está autenticado na sessão atual  e também o chamado atual. Outra observação é que da forma que implementei seguindo suas orientações, quando submeto o formulário apenas o texto

Comment: da evolução é passada para o controler (tanto o id_usuario quanto o id_chamado) estão indo com o valor 0.

Comment: Pessoal que leu essa abordagem.. vocês têm alguma sugestão?... continuo com essa dificuldade.

Comment: @MarceloAlmeida Atualize sua pergunta com o que foi implementado, por favor.